# Bluetooth Low Energy [4.2 and later] - characteristics greater than 20 bytes with Qt on Linux

Tags: linux, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

*I'm not sure this would be better on Electronics Stack Exchange.*

I've seen a few questions similar to this, but pre BLE 4.2 days, before it was possible to have characters of greater than 20 bytes, but these questions are outdated now.

To anyone who's not aware, from BLE 4.2 onwards, you have been able to send far more than 20 bytes in a characteristic. So, if you've not come across this, I have successfully been transferring characteristics of 240 odd bytes between iOS and a Silicon Labs device for well over a year.

I have recently set up a Nordic embedded device and knocked up a Qt GUI to transfer data between the Nordic device and the Qt app running on Linux, using the Bluez stack. It will transfer 20 byte characteristics just fine.

So, I increased the Nordic's characteristics to 40 bytes, but Qt is not playing at all with it.

I am confident things are right at the Nordic end because if I use a little Android app and query the 40 byte characteristic it reads all 40 bytes. This makes me think that the issue is at the Laptop end.

I have various unknowns:

1. Is my laptop really BT4.2. It's hard to know as Linux calls it an unknown device and its USB vendor and type number tell me it's an Intel device, yet the IDs seem to give me multiple possibilities.

hciconfig tells me that I am running HCI Version 4.2 and LMP Version 4.2. That, to me, suggests larger characteristics should work.

2. Can Linux itself cope with characteristics  of greater than 20 bytes?
3. Can Qt cope with characteristics  of greater than 20 bytes?

I am running Mageia 6 and Qt Creator 4.2.1 with Qt 5.9.4 kit.

I have no Windows or iOS device with LE new enough for larger characteristics. Also, Windows is a bit of a pain when it comes to LE...

Edit:

btmon gives this when it receives a 40 byte chatacteristic:

```
 ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 27        #1026 [hci0] 577.032058
      ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22
        Handle: 0x0010
          Data: 35303120546869732069732061206c6f6e672063
```

This is sending out a string from the Nordic:

```
"%1 This is a long characterstic %1",Messno,MessNo
```

MessNo gets incremented every time the Noridic sends out a message. This gets truncated to xxxx This is a long

So, this suggests to me that it's getting truncated either by the BT stack on the assumption that this is what the Qt app is digesting.

Comment: Nothing was changed in 4.2 regarding characteristic length. It has always been 512 bytes maximum since 4.0. However you need a large MTU in order to transfer long values when Notify, Indicate or Write Without Response is being used to transfer the value. So in what direction are you transferring your value? Can you post a log from the btmon command line utility that shows the packets?

Comment: I think what changed from 4.2 was the ability to send more than 20 bytes in one characteristic in one transaction. Not wanting to be pedantic, but I think that is an important difference. :) The data goes in both directions, but to start with I was attempting from Laptop to Nordic based embedded device. I have tried going the other way round and what happens is that the laptop truncates the 40 bytes from the Nordic to only 20. I will look into btmon to see whether I can get some data and post it in the question. Can I run this at the same time as, or instead of, the Qt app?

Comment: OK, forget the last question, it's clear you HAVE to run them both together!

Comment: You should first start btmon, then run your Qt app as usual and reproduce the issue. Btmon will then have captured and printed all packets in the terminal. But where did you get the information about that 4.2 added ability to send more than 20 bytes in one transaction? It has always been possible since 4.0, as long as the MTU is sufficient.

Comment: btmon is a very cool program! Not seen that before. I've ammended the question with extra info. I must apologise it is the Link Layer Payload that increases with BT4.2 - not MTU - as shown here: https://community.cypress.com/thread/13828    However, the point remains the same that throughput increases massively from 4.1 to 4.2 So maybe if I really do have 4.2 it's Bluez that stunts the maximum payload.

Comment: Seems the nordic device cuts the value because of the MTU has not been negotiated to a higher value. Can you try negotiate a high MTU from the nordic side? Do you by the way see any MTU Request packets in btmon?

Comment: As I said in the question, I do not believe the issue is at the Nordic end because I can connect my Android phone and use Light Blue to connect to the Nordic. With this, the Light Blue program sees and reads all forty bytes of the characteristic. I am reasonably confident the issue is at the Linux end, whether that be Qt or Bluez I do not know.

Comment: The btmon log entry clearly shows that the nordic device only sends a 20 byte long value and that must be because the MTU has the default value of 23. So try negotiate a larger value. It would also be good with the full btmon log because then we can see any MTU Request / Responses.

Comment: I have just stumbled across something. If I read the characteristic with the Android  it is forty bytes long. If I subscribe it only reads 20 bytes. I need to read rather than subscribe in Linux and see if that issue follows it. It may be something in the Nordic or LE in general set up that changes between read and notify.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, with Notify you are restricted to the MTU. With Read however you are not, since the local Bluetooth stack will use Read Blob Request to continue the read with the next offset until the whole value has been read.

Comment: You did say that and I just didn't appreciate what you were saying. I'm looking in to how you negotiate longer length notification characteristics work with the Nordic. Will report back in a bit. Many thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @Emil many thanks for your help, I had, indeed, to up the max MTU size at the Nordic end. Feel free to add an answer saying that and that it's nothing to do with Qt or Linux and I will gladly accept and up vote. You more than deserve it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the MTU size from the nordic device. It has nothing to do with Qt.